# how to find the english and chinese combination records in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

In pandas, data frame has 2 columns like "FirstName" and "LastName". From that columns "FirstName" column would be either english or chinese combination and same as "LastName" column would be either chinese or english combination. so, i want to display the those records of english-chinese combination in dataframe.

```
 code snippet:

      df.loc[df['FirstName'].str.contains(r'[a-zA-Z]+') & df['FirstName'].str.contains(r'[一种-ž]+'))]
```

I do not know this code snippet whether it's working or not.

my input dataframe is:

```
         FirstName          LastName

        jocovich            nadhal
        smith               pointing
        西德哈斯             supreet
        yuvi                雷迪
        bsreddy             rakshita
        sreeja              巴尔加维
        雷迪                西德哈斯
        Cédric             LEMARCHAND
        Radosław           Piotrowski
```

above is the my data frame. but my required output is like below:

```
        FirstName          LastName

         西德哈斯             supreet
         yuvi                雷迪
         sreeja              巴尔加维
```

I want to display the engilsh-chinese or chinese-english records from dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for the unicodes as i do here. You can inverse the matches as well:

```
df.query("FirstName.str.contains(r'[\u4e00-\u9FFF]', regex=True) or LastName.str.contains(r'[\u4e00-\u9FFF]', regex=True)") 

or 

df[(df['FirstName'].str.contains(r'[\u4e00-\u9FFF]', regex=True)) | ( df['LastName'].str.contains(r'[\u4e00-\u9FFF]', regex=True))]
```

or to not match both chinese first and last names as well:

```
df[((df['FirstName'].str.contains(r'[\u4e00-\u9FFF]', regex=True)) | ( df['LastName'].str.contains(r'[\u4e00-\u9FFF]', regex=True))) & (~df['FirstName'].str.contains(r'[\u4e00-\u9FFF]', regex=True) | (~df['LastName'].str.contains(r'[\u4e00-\u9FFF]', regex=True)))]
```

output:

```
  FirstName LastName
2      西德哈斯  supreet
3      yuvi       雷迪
5    sreeja     巴尔加维
```

Comment: it showing  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @user98 i updated with a second option to try that doesn't use query

Comment: there is small correction.
in my  problem statement , if chinese language detects both columns don't need to display record. but it is displaying. how can i solve that issue.

Comment: @user98 i tested against your new data and it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,Logic is  just check whether the string can be encoded only with ASCII characters.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
df = pd.DataFrame({"FirstName":["jocovich","smith"," 西德哈斯","yuvi"," bsreddy","sreeja"],"LastName":["nadhal","pointing","supreet","雷迪","rakshita","巴尔加维"],"blah":["example","example","example","example","example","example"]})


def isEnglish(s):
    o = list(s)
    ot = []
    for n in o:
        try:
            n.encode(encoding='utf-8').decode('ascii')
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            ot.append(False)
        else:
            ot.append(True)

    if ot==[True,False] or ot == [False,True]:
        return True
    else:
        return False


output = df[df[["FirstName","LastName"]].apply(lambda x: isEnglish(x),axis=1)]
```

output

```
  FirstName LastName     blah
2      西德哈斯  supreet  example
3      yuvi       雷迪  example
5    sreeja     巴尔加维  example
```

Comment: i assumed your dataframe has two columns FirstName and LastName.it will work for any number of rows.if df has more columns then need some modification.

Comment: there are 16 columns including these 2 columns (FirstName and LastName)
how this is possible to take as a dataframe only 2 columns.

Comment: i have changed the answer.check it

Comment: can u please add some more example columns and provide the answer?